# App Widget onUpdate not called when onReceive method exists

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have the following code in my `AppWidgetProvider` class.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Log.i("Custom", "Update");
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("Custom", "Recieve");
}
```

If I comment out the `onReceive` method the `onUpdate` method will be invoked each time I add the widget to the homescreen, if I do not it does not run. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Log.i("Custom", "Update");
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    Log.i("Custom", "Recieve");
}
```

If you take a look at the [`AppWidgetProvider`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.java&q=AppWidgetProvider.java&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) code, you will see that it invokes the `onUpdate` method. So, you must call the default `onUpdate` method of the super class.

Comment: Thanks, really should have picked that up myself!